# On implications of Schrodingers Cat regarding macroscopic quantum states and decoherence

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, theoretical-physics

How exactly did Schrodingers Cat lead to development regarding macroscopic quantum states and decoherence? One often hears that the thought experiment was the initiator to the question, whether quantum mechanics also applies to the macroscopic world - but so far I couldn't find any reliable sources that state this.

Comment: What kind of source are you looking for? Some important paper on decoherence acknowledging Schrödinger? A history book on macroscopic quantum states that starts with the thought experiment?

Comment: "A history book on macroscopic quantum states that starts with the thought experiment" would be ideal, but actually any source that comments on the connection is useful for me.

Comment: Answer to comment (as it does not provide much more detail): [Amir Caldeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amir_Caldeira), known for the Caldeira-Legget model, one of the first models for [quantum dissipation]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dissipation), starts his book [*An Introduction to Macroscopic Quantum Phenomena and Quantum Dissipation*](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Macroscopic_Quantum_P/HKnoAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by referring to Schrödinger's cat (right away in the first paragraph of the introduction).